# Magento 2, get Min and Max price in Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I am trying to get **Min & Max price** in **Layered Navigation** and I am using a third party extension for layered navigation..

By using below script, I am trying to get Min & Max price for filter collection.

```
  public function getPriceRange($filter){
     $Filterprice = array('min' => 0 , 'max'=>100);
    if($filter instanceof Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price) {
        $priceArr = $filter->getResource()->loadPrices(10000000000);           
        $Filterprice['min'] = reset($priceArr);
        $Filterprice['max'] = end($priceArr);
    }

    return $Filterprice;
}
```

But it says  loadprice not a method. Can any please suggest to get Min & Max price.

Comment: In which class you are trying to get it ? Post your full code here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get **min** and **max** price from any collection

For any collection.

```
$maxPrice = $productCollection->getMaxPrice();
$minPrice = $productCollection->getMinPrice();
```

Layer collection. Follow Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php

```
$this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
$this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-get-min-price-max-price-product-collection/)

Comment: @Qaisar..i updated my script. how can i get the product collection with filter object.

Comment: @Ramesh i updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Magento 2.2.4 version. How can i implement the script above in my FilterRenderer.php using D.I. approach? Sorry, I'm a Magento newbie.

Comment: @JakePucan follow https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-get-product-collection/
after that use this will give you desire result.
`$block->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
$block->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();`

Comment: @QaisarSatti I've red that already but how can I set that in filter.php https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-price-slider/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/filter.phtml Do i need to remove `$range =  $this->getPriceRange($filter);` ? Since the min & max price are from that function.

Comment: @QaisarSatti You made a typo in '$porductCollection'

Comment: I'm using searchcriteria for graphql. I want this max and min price at graphql. I tried through #searchResult object but it is not working V2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getPriceRange($filter)
{
    $max = $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
    $min = $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();
    $Filterprice = ['min' => $min, 'max' => $max];
    return $Filterprice;
}
```